# BeautifulSoup выдает пустую строку

Tags: python

Всем привет! Столкнулся с такой проблемой: BeautifulSoup вроде срабатывает, но выводит пустоту (хотя на странице есть нужный элемент). Что я делаю не так? Нужно спарсить ответ (r.text) и если в ответе есть определенное слово- вывести его на print:

```
r = requests.get ('http://mysite.com/')
status = r.status_code
if status == 200:
    soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text)
    h3 = soup.find_all('слово что я ищу')
    print(h3)
```

результат работы скрипта- просто [], а хотелось бы увидеть искомое слово

Comment: Вы ищете какое-то произвольное слово или html тег?

Comment: именно определенное слово, например weather

Answer (score 1):

Исходя из [документации](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs3/documentation.html#The%20basic%20find%20method:%20findAll(name,%20attrs,%20recursive,%20text,%20limit,%20**kwargs)) нужно использовать ещё атрибут text:

```
soup.findAll(text="слово что я ищу")
```

И на выходе будете получать или ваше значение или пустоту.

Но я бы рекомендовал искать через регулярки:

```
soup.findAll(text=re.compile("слово что я ищу"))
```

Comment: до этого гуглил, люди почему то не рекомендовали регулярки (скорость?)

Comment: да, но судя по выводу с примеров если это слово часть строки то выведет строку, а в первом варианте только это слово

Comment: soup.findAll(text="слово что я ищу") этот вариант так же выводит [], soup.findAll(text=re.compile("слово что я ищу")) этот вариант выводит всю страницу в формате json (ответ на запрос- в json)

Comment: Ну так получается он отрабатывает правильно, надо тогда давать ему не всю страницу при ините BeautifulSoup а часть в которой делаете проверку и которую хотели бы вывести, если я правильно понял задачу

Comment: понял, как тогда сделать так, чтобы только при найденном слове 'weather" выводится print ('слово найдено')?

Comment: @dimahimma Вам нужно искать слово на всем сайте? Т.е если оно там вообще есть, выводим `True` ?

Comment: да, там по api вся страничка выводится в json. нужно сделать поиск слова, и если  есть оно- print слово найдено, если нет- пропустить

Comment: @dimahimma `if word in str(soup): print('Found')` пробовали?

Comment: попробую отпишусь как прошло, интересно как обработается soup размером в 1 мб

Comment: @dimahimma 1- откуда json взялся? BeautifulSoup работает с html. Код у вас soup из r.text создаёт. Если r.text содержит json, то используйте r.json(), а не BeautifulSoup 2- зачем конструировать soup объект из html, только для того чтобы его сразу назад html превратить str(soup). Посмотрите работает ли для вас: `word in r.text`